# QTableView - what signal is sent when user selects a row by clicking to it?

Tags: qt, qtableview

Is there a signal which is emitted when  the user selects a row in `QTableView` by mouse (single selection model)?

Comment: It absolutely has to be the mouse?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Each view has a Selection model :

```
QItemSelectionModel * QAbstractItemView::selectionModel () const
```

and with the selection model you can retrieve lots of informations, in your case :

```
QModelIndexList QItemSelectionModel::selectedRows ( int column = 0 ) const
```

So :

```
myTableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
```

You can then retrieve this informations through a signal like :

```
void QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged ( const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected )   [signal]
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Alternative way to detect clicking on elements of your table view is using "void QAbstractItemView::clicked ( const QModelIndex & index )" signal